# Use of diophantine equation (money problems, 3 variables)

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

My friend has in his wallet some notes of $\displaystyle{ 20 }$ , $\displaystyle{ 50 }$ and $\displaystyle{ 100 }$ euros.
He has $\displaystyle{ 15 }$ notes and the total value of them is $\displaystyle{ 690 }$ euros. Tell me the amount of $\displaystyle{ 20 }$ , $\displaystyle{ 50 }$ and $\displaystyle{ 100 }$ euros he has in his wallet.

My solution:

$\displaystyle{ 20x+50y+100z=690 \Leftrightarrow 2x+5y+10z=69 (1) }$

$\displaystyle{ x+y+z=15 (2) }$

$\displaystyle{ x,y,z> 0 }$

$\displaystyle{ y\equiv 1 mod 2 }$  and $\displaystyle{ 5\cdot14=70 > 69 }$ 
 so $\displaystyle{ y< 14 }$.

Then, $\displaystyle{ y=1,3,5,7,9,11,13 }$.

Also $\displaystyle{ x\equiv 2 mod 5  }$. 
Then, $\displaystyle{ x=2,7,12 }$.

We also have that $\displaystyle{ 10\cdot7=70 >69 }$, so $\displaystyle{ z<7 }$.

From the equation $\displaystyle{ (2) }$ we get that $\displaystyle{ (x,y) = (7,9) , (7,11) , (7,13) , (12,5) , (12,7), (12,9), (12,11), (12,13) }$ are rejected.
We know that $\displaystyle{ z<7 }$, so $\displaystyle{(x,y) = (2,1), (2,3), (2,5), (7,1) }$ are rejected, too.

So I check every $\displaystyle{ (x,y) = (2,7) , (2,9), (2,11), (2,13)}$ (rejected because $\displaystyle{z=0}$ ) ,$\displaystyle{(7,3), (7,5), (7,7), (12,1), (12,3)}$ (rejected because $\displaystyle{z=0}$ ) to find out which ones are ok with equations $\displaystyle{ (1) , (2) }$.
The final answer is : $\displaystyle{ x=7, y=5, z=3 }$.

My question:

How can I find the solution using parameters? Thanks!

Comment: I found a much easier way to get the x,y,z values but still not by using parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by *"by using parameters"*?

Comment: Solving 2x+5y=W and finding x,y with a parameter and then solving W+10z=69 and finding w,z with parameters.. And then taking into account that x+y+z=15 and x,y,z>0 we can find the right parameters. Something like that..

Comment: That raises the very similar question of what you mean by *"...finding $x$, $y$* (or *$w$, $z$*) *with parameters"*?

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting equation (2) from equation (1) twice yields
$$3y+7z=39.$$
Since $y$ and $z$ are positive integers, there is precisely one solution which is quickly found.

Answer (score 0):

"OP" has asked for Parametric solution to below mentioned simultaneous equations:

$\displaystyle{ 2x+5y+10z=69  }$

$\displaystyle{ x+y+z=15  }$

The solution is given below:

$(x,y,z)=[(5k+2),(k+4),(k+2) ]$

From the above mentioned solution, it can be seen that $(x,y,z)= (7,5,3)$, for $k=1$,

is the only solution that satisfies both the two simultaneous equations.

Comment: Parametric solution will ordinarily mean that any choice of a parameter will generate a solution, i.e. a family of solutions is expressed through choices of the parameter.  But it isn't obvious how substitution of $x=5k+2,y=k+4,z=k+2$ would satisfy either equation.  It would improve your Answer to clarify what you mean by a parametric solution.